# The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController cannot be resolved error after adding the "spring-security-web"

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I added below to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

to resolve the error in my `servlet-config.xml`

```
 <http pattern="/api/login" security="none" /> // error line
 // error : The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use <http>: 
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
```

But when I modify the pom with that above entry my @RestController get an error.

in the line

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

it says "**The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController cannot be resolved**"

Answer (score 3):

Switch to the latest version (currently, 4.3.3.RELEASE).The Spring @RestController annotation has only been available in spring-web since version 4.0.1 [[1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)].

In Maven this would mean including/replacing the dependency in your pom.xml file:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```